# When deleting files, I encountered a problem that is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, fs

Recently I used nodejs to practice a project.
Need to write a function to delete files. The code is written like this.

```js
/**
 * delete cover
 */
  export const deleteResourcesCovers = async (covers: Array<CoverModel>) => {
  covers.map(cover => {
fs.unlink(`uploads/cover/${cover.filename}`, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

fs.unlink(`uploads/cover/resized/${cover.filename}-thumbnail`, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

fs.unlink(`uploads/cover/resized/${cover.filename}-medium`, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

fs.unlink(`uploads/cover/resized/${cover.filename}-large`, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
  });
};
```

This code is placed in the middleware.

However, such an error was encountered during execution. Where can the gods help me.

[image]

Comment: There's a ton of problems with your code. Your filenames need be surrounded with quotes, but it also seems that `covers` is not actually an error...

Comment: The filepath has quotation marks, but it was copied just now. Did not notice.
Is there anything wrong with the grammar?
Why is covers.map not a function?

Comment: Still the wrong quotes. If `covers.map` is not a function, it means that `covers` is not an array. I can't tell why it isn't, because I can't tell how `deleteResourcesCovers` is called.

Comment: Is the covers array not receiving the id, so the 4 files to be deleted cannot be found

Comment: It's not called correctly because covers is not an array

Comment: My level is limited, so how should I write it correctly?

Comment: As I said, I think this function is called incorrectly. So the bug is probably not in this snippet, but in the code that _calls_ `deleteResourcesCovers`

Comment: `/**
 * delete cover
 */
router.delete(
  '/covers/:coverId',
  authGuard,
  deleteResourcesCovers,
  coverController.destroy,
);`  The routing file is calling deleteResourcesCovers